# findOneAndUpdate creates new entry in upsert mode with $set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code and would like some help from the experts.

I have a logging system in a mongoose collection, where when I initiate a new job I create a new log entry and once the job is finished, I use the findOneAndUpdate command to try to update the existing record. Below is the line of code:

```
const log = await Publisher.findOneAndUpdate(
    filter, {
      $set: {
        status
      }
    }, {
      new: true,
      upsert: true
    }).exec();
```

Can someone tell me why it's not finding the existing log entry and creating a new duplicated entry?

The filter value is a JSON: { "job": { "input": { "prop1": "value1" } } }. The value stored in value1 can contain semi-colons and forward slashes. I checked that the value is the same in the initial log entry and the filter JSON.

Thank you,

Comment: I am running "mongoose": "5.10.9"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter is the problem

Instead of this:  `{ "job": { "input": { "prop1": "value1" } } }`

try this:  `{ "job.input.prop1": value1 }`
`"value1"` can be just a variable. mongoose will convert into JSON

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. This is getting me one step closer, the filter is now working but I am still getting two duplicate entries in my collection. One with initial status STARTED and the newer row with status FINISHED. The rest of the data is identical. Any way to avoid duplicating entries? It's as if it's not seeing the upsert...

Comment: Every time u update with the corrected filter, you get a "new" duplicate document?? Are u sure its "new"? and by the way, even if you have more than one document that corresponds to the filter, only "one" document will get updated. cuz u are using findOneAndUpdate(notice the "one" here)

Comment: All is well now. I think it took a while for new code to propagate, leading to false alarm. The filter syntax was definitely the problem.

Comment: Ok good to know. It would be great if u accept my answer